# PostgreSQL database designer that supports PostGIS geometry data types

Tags: postgis, postgresql, software-recommendations, geometry-data-type

Does anyone know if there are PostgreSQL database modeling software or apps that support PostGIS geometry data types?

I know pgModeler is supposed to but I have been unable to get this installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using DBeaver to generate ER Diagrams. Geometry is recognized:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are at least two solutions:

pgModeller available here: https://pgmodeler.io

or

dBeaver available here: https://dbeaver.io/download/